# How can i access the properties of a sub class using GetType().GetProperties()

Tags: vb.net

Is it posible to get all the properties of a class **including the child task within**

```
  Class Car
  Property Speed
    property Wheels(3) as Wheel


  Class Wheel
   Property Size
   Property Type
  End Class
 End Class
```

if i use this:

```
Dim ArrayOfProperties() As Reflection.PropertyInfo = Car.GetType().GetProperties()
```

i can get the properties Speed and Wheels, but i can't get Size and Type. How do i get the sub class properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not in one fell swoop.

To get the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) of a type use the [GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx) operator. In the following example `Car` is a *type* rather than an *instance* of `Car`.

```
Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(Car.Wheel).GetProperties()
```

You can get all the nested [Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) of a [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) using the [GetNestedTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
For Each t As Type In GetType(Car).GetNestedTypes()
    Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = t.GetProperties()
Next
```

So all you have to do is to add all those properties into a single list.

```
Dim all As New List(Of PropertyInfo)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is there a way of doing this if you are not sure if the object is a car object or any other object?

Comment: Use the [TypeOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) operator. `If (TypeOf obj Is Car) Then`